# Do better job + V-ing

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases

Does the sentence: "**I can do a better job working with them!**" mean "**I can do a better job if i work with them**" or "**I can work with them better (than someone else)**"?

Are there any other general structure similar with this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently no problem in distinguishing at least three possible meanings as made specific through context. However, I find no supporting evidence.

- *1/ choosing them to work with, 2/ as someone working with them, 3/ working with them rather than leaving everything up to them*

(*The apostrophe gives sentence stress*)

- The people in group A have a better control than those in group B. So I am interested in people in group A, I can do a (')better job working with (')them! (*either possibility of sentence stress seems meaningful*)
- This teacher is not counselling his pupils well; I wouldn't have them do all these exercises; I can do a 'better job working with them!
- Having the task done by a subcontractor and giving up all initiative to their crew is not the best way to obtain good results: I can do a better job 'working with them!

Comment: So you mean that the context will determine the meaning of the sentence? The persons speaking in the sentence is a man who is talking to his boss about a team that his boss doesn't like. So i think the meaning is the 2nd as you show in the answer.(Sorry for my quite bad english, i have started to learn it recently)

Comment: @user383745 That is  what I think; I also think that in all three cases "if I work with them" can be used to replace "working with them" and that in each case the context will determine the nuance that is proper.